# What's the purpose of the "Post is related to a rapidly changing event." label on my question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

My question [Could Steve have hurt the ISS?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21219/12102) has a type of comment added that I haven't seen before. The text is `Post is related to a rapidly changing event.`

Is there a stackexchange term that describes this kind of comment? What is the intended purpose or function? Has it been used here in SXSE often? Ever?

In this particular case, Steve has been known in the Aurora community for at least several months. There does not seem to be anything about it that is rapidly changing. Steve isn't an event either, it's a regularly observed phenomenon. I'm curious why this comment claims otherwise.

> [image]

Comment: That post should probably have that annotation. Even if it is news (kinda), there are no rapidly changing aspects of it. I have removed it.

Comment: @Hohmannfan I put that on there because I believed that with the recent investigation of Steve that there may soon be more information than is currently available.

Comment: @uhoh It has been used in the past on other questions where the information might change soon after the question was posted. For example, it was added to my question about the government shutdown in 2013, since I asked the question pretty much the moment the shutdown was announced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a post notice on the question. Specifically, it is the "current event" notice, which is appended to a question when there have been recent developments in regards to the subject of the question that may have an impact on how accurate the initial answers may be. In other words, answers posted before information is gleaned from the new developments may be lacking important details or even altogether wrong!